# Formatting datetime2 in LaTex to 4th September, 2016 without the current day?

Tags: formatting, datetime, datetime2, date

I'm currently using

```
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}
```

and I'm getting 
Sunday 4th September, 2016

with the commands `\today` or with `\newdate{example}{01}{09}{2016}` (outside of `\begin{document}`) and `\displaydate{example}` inside the document.

How can I reformat this date to not have the name of the day in it (Best would be with using datetime2)? So like 4th September, 2016. With the "th" as a high letter like this: [image]

Full document example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, DIV=calc, headings=small]{scrreprt}
%Used packages
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{datetime}

%Other definitions
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\newdate{sample}{31}{01}{2017}


\begin{document}
\displaydate{sample}\\
\today
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please post a compilable document, since we don't know which command was used by you to show the date at all.

Comment: It is a fragment only, so far. Please post a document, not just macro calls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you asked for a `datetime2` solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}

\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=raise,monthyearsep={,\space}}

\DTMsavedate{sample}{2017-01-31}

\begin{document}
\DTMusedate{sample}

\today

\end{document}
```

Produces

[image: 31st January, 2017 4th September, 2016]

Requires [`datetime2`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2) (base code) and [`datetime2-english`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-english) (for `en-GB` style).

Answer (score 2):

The name of day is defined with the macro `\dayofweekname`, you can simply deactivate it with `\renewcommand{\dayofweekname}[3]{\relax}`

**Code**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, DIV=calc, headings=small]{scrreprt}
%Used packages
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{datetime}
%Other definitions
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\newdate{sample}{31}{01}{2017}

\renewcommand{\dayofweekname}[3]{\relax}

\begin{document}
\displaydate{sample}\\
\today
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: It's simpler to just use the `nodayofweek` package option.