# datetime2 define dates "globally" outside of \begin{document}

Tags: formatting, datetime, datetime2, date

When using the datetime package, I could define dates "globally" like this:

```
\newdate{sample}{03}{09}{2016}
\begin{document}
\displaydate{sample}
\end{document}
```

Can anyone tell me, how this is possible with datetime2 library because I just don't get it somehow...

Full document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, DIV=calc, headings=small]{scrreprt}
%Used packages
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{datetime}

%Other definitions
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\newdate{sample}{31}{01}{2017}

\begin{document}
\displaydate{sample}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you read section `4 Storing and Using Dates and Times` in the datetime2 documentation?

Comment: I must have just read over it... :( But still thanks for the info.

Comment: In this question (the link) I just wanted to asked how to reformat today's date... Here I wanted to know how to define dates in the datetime2 library. So I guess not.

Comment: I don't agree that the questions are duplicates. [I've posted on meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6866/non-duplicate-question-with-overlapping-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is
[here:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327956/formatting-datetime2-in-latex-to-4th-september-2016-without-the-current-day/327964#327964)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}

\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=raise,monthyearsep={,\space}}

\DTMsavedate{sample}{2017-01-31}

\begin{document}
\DTMusedate{sample}

\end{document}
```

Thanks to [Nicola Talbot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862/nicola-talbot)