# How to customize \printdate?

Tags: isodate

How to get the output as shown below by customizing `\printdate`?

[image]

Here is the minimal code

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[english]{isodate}

\begin{document}

\printdate{2017-05-12}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @CarLaTeX That's a different package ... (Ah, didn't see your answer.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Indeed, I've marked as duplicate only after that the OP accepted my answer, but still I'm not sure... if you can find a solution with `isodate` maybe the question isn't a duplicate...

Comment: Look at Nicola Talbot's comment to my answer (and my edit), thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `datetime2` instead of `isodate`, I took the code from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327964/101651).

*Edit:*

Sorry, I copied the code without carefully reading the package documentation.

My previous code included useless instructions, as Nicola Talbot correctly pointed out.

I've simplyfied it:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[en-GB]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=raise,monthyearsep={,\space}}

\begin{document}

\DTMdate{2017-05-12}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or just `\DTMdate{2017-05-12}` (instead of saving and using the date).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Blame on me! I copied the code without reading the manual carefully, thank you!